# Import VueJs component based on conditions

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am working on micro frontend architecture where multiple teams working on different pages or may be on a single page.

I have a component in vue2(**Feature1.vue**) and I have to import this dynamically based on the need of the component. if **Feature1.vue** is not needed then it should not be part of the bundle.

if any team needs that component then It will be part of the build and bundle size also increase.

Using **props** or any **flag** if true then only it should be part of the bundle if false it should remove from the bundle. Is it possible?

I am using Vue 2 and I am not using Vue Router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Circular-References-Between-Components

This article is not relevant by name, but offers dynamic import solution.

```
beforeCreate: function () {
  this.$options.components.TreeFolderContents = require('./tree-folder-contents.vue').default
}

components: {
  TreeFolderContents: () => true ? import('./tree-folder-contents.vue') : undefined
}
```